# How to fix high CPU usage found using performance profiling results?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, thread-safety, cpu-usage

#### Intro

We are building a c# data collector that collects tagged data from an OPC source (data being sampled every 1/2 second. The code runs well except for the fact that it uses around 25% of the CPU (XEON 2.8GHz 8GB). Using the Visual Studio Performance Profiler, we got the following :
[Overall CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQJAB.png)

We identified 2 functions with high CPU consumption : [Hot path leading to the 2 high consumption functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81drd.png)
We are noticing that the function, itself, doesn't consume much CPU ressources (Self CPU around 1.5%) but around 50% of the whole app consumption (Total CPU around 50%).

Digging further into the "PrepareTags() function, we found that SemaphoreSlim.Release() and Wait() methods are mostly responsible for the CPU usage : [PrepareTags() function consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSW3g.png)

**Global code structure**

When the program begins, the 3 main threads are started. The one I'm focussing on here is the REST API thread. These threads are "permanent" and kept active as long as the application runs. Also, each main thread will start new threads, some are permanent while others will execute and stop.

Based on my observations, **around 40 threads** are simultaneously active with small variations caused by threads being started and stopped. Thread number is kept constant so **it seems there is no deadlocks**.

*3 Main threads are starting*

```
public void StartThreads()
        {
            WriteLog.WriteFollowLog("CollecterService : is Started");

            //set up default culture
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Culturesetting"]);
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

            listOfTagUpdated = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
            listOfTag = new Dictionary<string, TagSourceAddressObject>();
            tcpMemory = new TagMemoryFinFout();
            tagAdressMemoryForStat = new TagAdressMemoryFinFout();
            tagMemory = new TagMemoryLastValue(false);

            //configuration
            try
            {
                // Creation of the Stat thread
                this.statThread = new ThreadForCalculation(listOfTag, tagAdressMemoryForStat, tagMemory, tcpMemory);

                // Creation of the REST API client thread
                this.restApiThread = new ThreadRestApiClient(listOfTag, tcpMemory, listOfTagUpdated, tagMemory);

                // Creation of the OPCDA Thread
                this.opcDaThread = new ThreadOpcDaClient(listOfTag, tcpMemory, tagAdressMemoryForStat, tagMemory, listOfTagUpdated);
                if (configuration != null)
                {
                    this.configuration.StartTracking(this.restApiThread);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLog.WriteErrorLog(ex);
            }

        }
```

The RestAPIThreadClient will also start 3 threads **including the permanent "PrepareTags" thread**.

*RestAPIThread permanent thread starts 3 more permanent threads*

```
...
 // Start the authentication and the websocket handlers for this connection
            this.AuthenticationConnectionThread = new Thread(CheckConnectionAuthentication);
            this.AuthenticationConnectionThread.Name = "AuthentificationConnectionThread";
            this.AuthenticationConnectionThread.Start();

            this.WebsocketConnectionThread = new Thread(CheckWebsocketConnection);
            this.WebsocketConnectionThread.Name = "WebsocketConnectionThread";
            this.WebsocketConnectionThread.Start();

            this.TcpPrepareTagThread = new Thread(PrepareTags);
            this.TcpPrepareTagThread.Name = "TcpPrepareThread";
            this.TcpPrepareTagThread.Start();
...
```

For better comprehension here is what a "TagValueObject" looks like :

```
TagValueObject newTag = new TagValueObject(null);
            newTag.TagID = tag.TagID;
            newTag.TagQuality = tag.TagQuality;
            newTag.TagTimeStamp = tag.TagTimeStamp;
            newTag.TagValue = tag.TagValue;
            newTag.TagName = tag.TagName;
```

The overall process is :

1. OPC server sends tag data to our collector (every 1/2 second)
2. The collector stores these in memory
3. After some processing they are redirected to an API on AWS

**The high CPU usage is observed in step 3**

#### What happens in step 3

**1. *PrepareTags()* gets called.**

*Function PrepareTags()*

```
private void PrepareTags()
     {
         WriteLog.WriteFollowLog("TCPRestAPIClient : Is Started");

         while (!stopWorking)
         {

             if (token != null)
             {
                
                 TagValueObject tag = tcpMemory.GetFirstTag();
                 if (tag != null)
                 {
                     tagsToSend.Add(tag);
                     int numOfTagsToReturn = 50;

                     if ((readyToSend == true && tagsToSend.Count > 0) || tagsToSend.Count >= numOfTagsToReturn)
                     {
                         readyToSend = false;


                         //WriteLog.WriteFollowLog("Start count:" + tagsToSend.Count.ToString());

                         List<TagValueObject> tags = tagsToSend.GetRange(0, tagsToSend.Count > numOfTagsToReturn ? numOfTagsToReturn : tagsToSend.Count);
                         tagsToSend.RemoveRange(0, tagsToSend.Count > numOfTagsToReturn ? numOfTagsToReturn : tagsToSend.Count);

                         //WriteLog.WriteFollowLog("End count:" + tagsToSend.Count.ToString() + " / Remaining: " + tcpMemory.TagMemorySlot.Count);

                         Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                         {
                             ProcessTagRequest(tags);
                         });
                         thread.Name = "PrepareTags";
                         thread.Start();
                        
                         
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

**2. We get a range of tags stored in memory through *"GetFirstTag()"* and start the ProcessTagRequest Thread**

*Function GetFirsTag()*

```
public TagValueObject GetFirstTag()
        {
            TagValueObject tag;
            if (valueUpdated.Wait(10))
            {
                //WriteLog.WriteFollowLog(String.Format("TagMemoryFinFout-GetFirstTag Semaphore(valueUpdated) : Entered. Available Slots = {0}", valueUpdated.CurrentCount));

                lock (thislock)
                {
                    tag = tagMemorySlot.FirstOrDefault();
                    tagMemorySlot.Remove(tag);
                }
                valueUpdated.Release();
                //WriteLog.WriteFollowLog(String.Format("TagMemoryFinFout-GetFirstTag Semaphore(valueUpdated) : Released. Available Slots = {0}", valueUpdated.CurrentCount));
            }
            else
            {
                tag = null;
            }

            return tag;
        }
```

**3. *"ProcessTagRequest()"* thread is started**

*Function ProcessTagRequest()*

```
private void ProcessTagRequest(List<TagValueObject> tags)
        {
            if (tags.Count == 0) return;

            try
            {
                sendData(tags, false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLog.WriteErrorLog("TCPRestAPIClient", ex);
            }
            //WriteLog.WriteErrorLog("Closed Thread");
        }
```

**4.  We finally send the data to the API through *sendData()* function.**

*Function sendData()*

```
private void sendData(List<TagValueObject> valueArray, Boolean externalMemory)
        {

            if (valueArray.Count > 0)
            {
                List<object> valueArrayAdjusted = new List<object>();

                foreach (var valueEntry in valueArray){
                    dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
                    data.value = valueEntry.TagValue;
                    data.date = valueEntry.TagTimeStamp;
                    data.quality = valueEntry.TagQuality;
                    data._id = valueEntry.TagID;
                    valueArrayAdjusted.Add(data);
                }
                var body = new
                {
                    tags = valueArrayAdjusted
                };


                Boolean sendFail = true;
                var tries = 0;
                do
                {
                    tries++;
                    IRestResponse response = APICall(Method.POST, "/senddata", body, token);
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        sendFail = false;
                       // WriteLog.WriteErrorLog("Senddata connected successfully : " + response.StatusCode + " " + response.Content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WriteLog.WriteFollowLog("Senddata failed to connect : " + response.StatusCode + " " + response.Content);
                    }
                } while (tries < 1 && sendFail);


                if (sendFail)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseExternalStorage"] == "true")
                        {
                            foreach (TagValueObject value in valueArray)
                            {
                                StoreInExternalMemory(value);
                            }
                            WriteLog.WriteFollowLog(String.Format("Senddata : Stored {0} tags in external memory", valueArray.Count));
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        WriteLog.WriteErrorLog("ThreatRestApiClient : " + e.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**My question is : How to reduce the CPU usage? What is wrong in this code, architecture?**

Comment: Starting a new thread for every PrepareTags() is not a good idea.

Comment: +1. Also, you're leaking your threads. That will eventually lead to problems. You always have to keep the reference to the thread somewhere, so you can wait for it to end.

Comment: You didn't specify what kind of object `tcpMemory` is, but I assume it's just some kind of list. Then your `PrepareTags()` method is busy-waiting. You need it to block (or sleep) when it has nothing to do.

Comment: @PMF When you mention leaking the threads, do you mean "deadlocks"? Original code is not mine and threads were piling up (around 2000) but CPU usage was lower... Now that I fixed the issue, CPU usage has gone up dramatically (4X). If no thread gets locked and their number is constant, do I still need to track them?

Comment: @Neil  I added more details about how the program is structured. *PrepareTags()* is a persistent thread. But yes, it is constantly looping and checking for tags in the "tcpMemory" *List<tagValueObjects>*. When tags are found, a *ProcessTagRequest()* thread is launched. The list is constantly being filled by the OPC server which sends data every 1/2 second.

Comment: @Neil I tried without creating a thread for each *PrepareTags()* execution.

No notable improvement though. Total thread number decreased a bit but CPU remained as high as before. Will continue digging...

Comment: Polling for a tag every 10ms isn't going to help either `valueUpdated.Wait(10)`  You should use an observer pattern rather than polling.

Comment: @RogerSt-Arneault. Yes, you should always track the threads, or you might not be able to properly terminate your application. And if a thread throws an exception,  it will go unnoticed. This has nothing to do with deadlocks,  though.

Comment: @Neil I completely agree. The thing is that I'm not sure I will have the opportunity to do so... This is existing code that I need to fix and I don't think they are willing to give me time to do so... I'll explore what it would imply... Thx!

Comment: @PMF Thx for the answer!